# extract a substring from an array of strings in python

Tags: python

Is there a way how to extract an array (or list) of substrings (all characters from position 1 to position 2) from all elements of a string array (or a list of strings) without making a loop?

For example, I have:
`aa=['ab1cd','ab2ef']` ,
and I want my output to be:
`out=['b1','b2']`

For a single string variable I would do 
`out=aa[1:3]`, but I can't figure how to do it for a list or array (without a loop).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will definitely need *some* kind of loop.  A list comprehension is the easiest way:

```
out = [x[1:3] for x in aa]
```

Comment: An alternative is `map(lambda x: x[1:3], aa)`

Comment: Thanks, you spared me a lot of time trying to figure it out! I usually work with IDL, and there most functions (including most string functions) can take an array as an argument. I assumed it is the same in Python, and I assumed wrong. Thanks again.