# Substring each element of an array column in PySpark 2.2

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to substring each element of an array column in PySpark 2.2. My df looks like the one below, which is
similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749555/parse-through-each-element-of-an-array-in-pyspark-and-apply-substring), although each element in my df has the same length before the hyphen delimiter.

```
+---------------------------------+----------------------+
|col1                             |new_column            |
+---------------------------------+----------------------+
|[hello-123, abcde-111]           |[hello, abcde]        |
|[hello-234, abcde-221, xyzhi-333]|[hello, abcde, xyzhi] |
|[hiiii-111, abbbb-333, xyzhu-222]|[hiiii, abbbb, xyzhu] |
+---------------------------------+----------------------+
```

I tried adjusting the udf in the prior question based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624523/extract-a-substring-from-an-array-of-strings-in-python) answer to obtain the output in `new_column` above, but no luck so far. Is there a way to make this work in PySpark 2.2?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T 

cust_udf = F.udf(lambda arr: [x[0:4] for x in arr], T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
df1.withColumn('new_column', cust_udf(col("col1")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using a different approach: explode the array, substring the elements, and then collect back to array.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    
df1\
   .withColumn('idx', F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
   .withColumn('exploded_col', F.explode(col('col1')))\
   .withColumn('substr_col', F.substring(col('exploded_col'),1,5))\
   .groupBy(col('idx'))\
   .agg(F.collect_set('substr_col').alias('new_column'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your udf approach works for me. Besides you can use `transform` with `substring`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('new_column', f.expr('transform(col1, x -> substring(x, 0, 5))')).show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                col1|          new_column|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[hello-123, abcde...|      [hello, abcde]|
|[hello-234, abcde...|[hello, abcde, xy...|
|[hiiii-111, abbbb...|[hiiii, abbbb, xy...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: When using my udf I get the error "Job aborted due to stage failure". Did you use a version after Pyspark 2.2.0? Transform is from Spark 2.4

Comment: Hmm interesting, it's possible 2.2 is not supporting returning array of string from udf yet ? I was using Pyspark 3+

Comment: Ended up using a different approach, couldn't manage to fix the udf error. Thanks though!